# How did Susannah and Edward become a part of the trip of Mr Starkes?

Tags: goosebumps

**NOTE: This book is entitled *Goosebumps: Night at the Terror Tower* by R.L. Stine. I don't know if many of you read these books but all answers are welcomed.**

For those who read this book, Susannah and Edward are the prince and princess. They forgot about their memory about being royalty when Morgred the Sorcerer casted a spell. This spell wiped out their memory and Morgred planted some new memories, in which they lived far away from royalty life and start a new life again to escape the danger of their uncle, the Lord High Executioner, because he wants to be the ruler by smothering the two siblings, so that he will be the one to obtain the power.

But LHE followed them using the three white stones - a stone which can bring you in past or future. In the mid part of the book, Sue and Eddie were having trouble with their memories, which later on they found out that their memories were all fake.

**My question is, how did they become part of Mr. Starkes tour group in Terror Tower if their memories was changed? Both their parents are dead, the king and queen?**